# Long computation causes ExecutorService to stop assigning new work

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I am optimizing PNG files by spawning 5 pngout.exe processes to work on a directory of PNG files. Since pngout is single-threaded, this results in a large speedup. Some images take a long time to optimize, upwards of 30 seconds, while the norm is <5 seconds. The problem:

- File 1 is large, 2-5 are small, total of 50 files but details of rest irrelevant.
- First five pngout processes spawn normally and start working
- 2-5 exit within 10 seconds
- 1 takes 45 seconds
- No new pngout processes are spawned during this, despite having four threads free
- Upon completion of 1, another five processes are spawned.

Code:

```
private final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    /* ^ instance var, below is in method */

    CompletionService<Boolean> comp = new ExecutorCompletionService<Boolean>(pool);
    List<Callable<Boolean>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Boolean>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        File infile = files[i];
        File outfile = new File(outdir, infile.getName());
        tasks.add(new CrushTask(crusher, infile, outfile));
    }
    for (Callable<Boolean> t : tasks)
        comp.submit(t);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        try {
            boolean res = comp.take().get();
            System.out.println(res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

All files are optimized properly, that part of the code works. The problem is that by waiting on large images, the entire process is massively slowed down. I get only a 40% improvement over single-threaded time.

What am I doing wrong?

edit: Fixed the issue, using some really ugly code. The problem is that to get the exit value of the processes I was spawning (to know when they are finished and if they succeeded) I was reading their stdout to nothing, since calling waitFor would hang forever. However, apparently using InputStreams makes threads choke.

So to get the exit value of the processes, instead of using this:

```
private static int discardStdOut(Process proc) throws IOException {
    final InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
    try {
        while (is.read() != -1)
            continue;
        return proc.exitValue();
    } finally {
        close(is);
    }
}
```

I am using this gross code:

```
private static int discardStdOut(Process proc) {
    int ret = -1;
    while (true) {
        try {
            ret = proc.exitValue();
            break;
        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It's gross but now the system works fine and always has 5 processes running.

late edit: StreamGobbler from [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4) is probably more proper.

Comment: What is the definition of the files variable?  Is it the full 50 files?

Comment: The files variable is an array containing all 50 input PNG files.

Comment: @Aleksei Vasiliev might be useful to get a thread dump right before 1 completes

Comment: Thanks, got a thread dump. All of the pool threads are in state Runnable, and all of them are in the same location in the code: locked by a BufferedInputStream while reading the stdout of their pngout process. I need to read their stdout to completion because Process.waitFor() will block forever otherwise. But apparently something about this is causing the threads to get stuck, even after their pngout process finishes and exits. So I've got no clue what to do now.

Comment: If you use `java.nio` classes instead of `java.io` at least they won't block and you won't get stuck. There is a fair bit of work to convert it over though, however it's worth it a) cos it will fix your problem and b) it's good to learn nio.

Comment: I need to empty the Process's stdout, and Java only gives access to it as an InputStream (buffered). Can that even be converted to use nio?

Comment: Curious: why waitFor hangs forever even when pngout finishes?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Thread starvation. You need to do a sleep or IO for java to manage threading properly. Its not the JVMs fault operating system threading is broken.